# Explanation for a function within xcorr in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Looking within the xcorr function, most of it is pretty straightforward, except for one function within xcorr called "findTransformLength".

```
function m = findTransformLength(m)
    m = 2*m;
    while true
        r = m;
        for p = [2 3 5 7]
            while (r > 1) && (mod(r, p) == 0)
                r = r / p;
            end
        end
        if r == 1
            break;
        end
        m = m + 1;
    end
```

With no comments, i fail to understand what this function is meant to acheive and what is the significance of p = [2 3 5 7]. Why those numbers specifically? Why not take a fixed FFT size instead? Is there a disadvantage(cause errors) to taking a fixed FFT size?

Comment: I guess it's related to a divide-conquer-combine pipeline in the DFT/FFT algorithm, likely to accelerate speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is used to get the integer closest to `2*m` that can be written in the form:

[image]

Either:

1. `m` is already of this form, then the loop

   ```
   for p = [2 3 5 7]
            while (r > 1) && (mod(r, p) == 0)
                r = r / p;
            end
    end
   ```

Will decrease `r` down to 1 and the `break` will be reached.

2. Or `m` has at least one other prime factor, and `r` will not reach 1. You go back to the look with `m+1` and so on until you reach a number of the right form.

As per why they do this, you can see on the [fft doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), in the Input arguments section:

> n — Transform length [] (default) | nonnegative integer scalar
>
> Transform length, specified as [] or a nonnegative integer scalar.
> Specifying a positive integer scalar for the transform length can
> **increase the performance of fft**. The length is typically specified as
> a power of 2 **or a value that can be factored into a product of small**
> **prime numbers**. If n is less than the length of the signal, then fft
> ignores the remaining signal values past the nth entry and returns the
> truncated result. If n is 0, then fft returns an empty matrix.
>
> Example: n = 2^nextpow2(size(X,1))